# I'm having problems with rectangle collision detection it only seems to get the first object

Tags: java

```
public class Player {

public Image player;
public double playerX, playerY, dx, dy, nextDirx, nextDiry;
public Object1 object;
public Rectangle playerRect = new Rectangle();
public Rectangle[] rect = new Rectangle[2];

public Player() throws SlickException {
    object = new Object1();
    player = new Image("Sprites/player/DOWN 0.png");
    playerX = 50;
    playerY = 50;
    dx = 0;
    dy = 0;
    playerRect.setBounds((int) playerX, (int) playerY, player.getWidth(), player.getHeight());
    for(int i = 0; i < object.objectMap.size(); i++) {
        rect[i] = new Rectangle(object.objectMap.get(i).rect.x, object.objectMap.get(i).rect.y, object.objectMap.get(i).rect.width, object.objectMap.get(i).rect.height);
    }
}

public void setXY(double x, double y) {
    playerX = x;
    playerY = y;
    dy = 0;
    dx = 0;
}

public double getX() {
    return playerX;
}

public double getY() {
    return playerY;
}

public void handleMoving(Input userInput) {
    if (userInput.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_LEFT)) {
        dx = -5;
        nextDirx = playerX - 5;
        nextDiry = playerY;
        playerRect.setBounds((int) nextDirx, (int) nextDiry, player.getWidth(), player.getHeight());
        for(int i = 0; i < rect.length; i++) {
            if (playerRect.getBounds().intersects(rect[i].getBounds())) {
                setXY(getX(), getY());
            } else {
                setXY(getX() + dx, getY() + dy);
            }
        }
    }
    if (userInput.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_RIGHT)) {
        dx = 5;
        nextDirx = playerX + 5;
        nextDiry = playerY;
        playerRect.setBounds((int) nextDirx, (int) nextDiry, player.getWidth(), player.getHeight());
        for(int i = 0; i < rect.length; i++) {
            if (playerRect.getBounds().intersects(rect[i].getBounds())) {
                setXY(getX(), getY());
            } else {
                setXY(getX() + dx, getY() + dy);
            }
        }
    }
    if (userInput.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_UP)) {
        dy = -5;
        nextDirx = playerX;
        nextDiry = playerY-5;
        playerRect.setBounds((int) nextDirx, (int) nextDiry, player.getWidth(), player.getHeight());
        for(int i = 0; i < rect.length; i++) {
            if (playerRect.getBounds().intersects(rect[i].getBounds())) {
                setXY(getX(), getY());
            } else {
                setXY(getX() + dx, getY() + dy);
            }
        }
    }
    if (userInput.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_DOWN)) {
        dy = 5;
        nextDirx = playerX;
        nextDiry = playerY + 5;
        playerRect.setBounds((int) nextDirx, (int) nextDiry, player.getWidth(), player.getHeight());
        for(int i = 0; i < rect.length; i++) {
            if (playerRect.getBounds().intersects(rect[i].getBounds())) {
                setXY(getX(), getY());
            } else {
                setXY(getX() + dx, getY() + dy);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

is my code but it's only working for the rectangle that is equal to [0] in the array, why is this?

i know that the array has the objects in because i can get all of the information from the other objects

```
            for(int i = 0; i < rect.length; i++) {
            if (playerRect.getBounds().intersects(rect[i].getBounds())) {
                System.out.println("You are inside the object: "+i);
                setXY(getX(), getY());//Stop moving    
            } else {
                setXY(getX() + dx, getY() + dy);//move
            }
        }
```

is what i want to be happening, but basically it will say i'm in all of the objects but it will only stop me from moving when i intersect with the rect[0] opposed to stopping me from moving with all of the indexes in the array.

Comment: May be only for first element returning `true` ? And define working also .

Comment: I take it `rect` is an array of objects?

Comment: Can you show the code where you populate `rect`?

Comment: is what I'm using and the other objects are in the array becuse if i do System.out.println(""+rect[i].getWidth); it returns all of them

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Don't put code in comments.  Instead [edit it into the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19184049/edit).  Then use code formatting for the code.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Comment: @Requa don't post blocks of code in the comments.  Edit your question and add the code there.  Also, please post more context - what does `playerRect().getBounds().intersects()` look like? show us the method that your `for` loop is in. Show us variable definitions.  Etc

Comment: Thank you Andrew this is my first question haha!

Comment: There isn't anything in particular wrong with that loop so I suspect your set/getXY methods have a problem or you've simplified the code so much that there isn't a problem any more. Try writing the smallest example you can that reproduces the problem and post that.

Comment: I have edited the post maybe it might be easier to understand my problem now.

Answer (score 0):

you are using `object.objectMap.get(i).rect.y` instead of `object.objectMap.get(i).rect.x` in the x parameter place.

```
 rect[i] = new Rectangle(object.objectMap.get(i).rect.y, object.objectMap.get(i).rect.y, object.objectMap.get(i).rect.width, object.objectMap.get(i).rect.height);
```

Corrected code

```
rect[i] = new Rectangle(object.objectMap.get(i).rect.x, object.objectMap.get(i).rect.y, object.objectMap.get(i).rect.width, object.objectMap.get(i).rect.height);
```

Comment: Oh yeah i didn't see that but regardless it still only collides with the first rectangle in the array.